# how to map versionKey __v into a custom field?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, graphql

I have the following schema:

```
const articleSchema = new Schema<IArticle>({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  overview: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

Because for each update I want to check if the current version of the object body is the same with the database object, I need to map the `__v` field (from db) named *versionKey* into a field in my schema/interface.

I can add it to *articleSchema* as `__v: Number` but the problem is with `GraphQL`, because I can't declare a type like this (a field name can not start with **__**). Anyway, I'm still not sure that a field `__v` from my schema will be mapped to the existing one of the collection. Also, I tried to use `versionKey`, but is undefined.

I need something like that:

```
const articleSchema = new Schema<IArticle>({
  ...,
  version: Number // which will be the __v field from collection
});
```

How you solve this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, some AI helped me :)))

can use __v field inside of schema, with an alias which will be used in `graphql` schema

```
 __v: {
    type: Number,
    alias: "version",
 },
```

a small drawback here is that I need to compare the `originalRecord.__v` with the upcomming object `record.version` (because `graphql` doesn't know about `__v` and `mongodb` doesn't know about `version` field)